# Finding the span of a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, calculus

I am trying to create a Function M-file that will take in a function handle, a real number, and another real number. The output of the function being the span of the inputted function handle. I am assuming the second real number input is always bigger and that the inputted function is always a quadratic function.

span(f,a,b)

Essentially, the function will take in the function from the function handle (f) and then finds the maximum and minimum values of that function between the intervals [a,b] and then takes the difference of the 2, thus giving us the span.

I am relatively new to Matlab. I am wondering what would be the best way to find the max and min of a function given an interval in Matlab.

I was thinking of using the first derivative test to determine the critical points and then using the extreme value theorem to test all critical points including the end points (a and b) to find max and min.

Comment: Your plan sounds nice, but don't forget that your function will not be given an analytical expression as input, but only a black box that tells you output values for specific inputs. You can't really compute the first derivative, only approximately, and in certain points. This *can* be enough, as long as your function is reasonable. Specifically for quadratic functions, you can even evaluate the function in a few (3?) points, and fit a quadratic polynomial to that (essentially arriving at an exact solution).

Comment: Why not describe the function using the coefficients of the polynomial? Then you can easily take the first derivative analytically, use that to evaluate the extrema, take the max and min...

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. Given that the function is quadratic, there will only be 1 critical point no matter what. That means all I have to do is test the 2 end points (a and b) and test that 1 single critical point and find the smallest and largest value amongst these 3 conditions.

Comment: Yup. Sounds right. Take a look at `poly` and `polyval`... should be useful to you.

Comment: hmmm, on that note. I am running into another bump. lets say I have 3 values: f(a), f(b), and f(criticalpoint). What is the best way to determine which of these 3 values is the max and which is the min?

Comment: max/min: you can concatenate those three scalars in a vector `v = [ f(a), f(b), f(criticalpoint) ];` then call `[maxval, idx] = max( v )` which returns you both the maximum *value* and the *index* of the max. val. in the vector. You could than add a switch/case statement [same for min]. Alternatively you manually compare those values in pairs.